# Waiting for POST to Complete and Returning the Status from Service

Tags: angular

I'm using the new `HttpClient` from `'@angular/common/http'`. My component and service is setup like the following:

**component.ts**

```
public async saveComment() {
    this._service.postComment(this.comment);

    // I want to wait for the post to complete and then update my comments list below

    this.comments = await this._service.getComments();
}
```

**service.ts**

```
public postComment(comment: string) {
    this._http.post(this.serviceUrl, { comment })
        .subscribe(
        response => {
            console.log(response);
        });
}
```

The `post` doesn't return any content. It only returns a `200` if it was successful or an error status if unsuccessful.

How can I wait for the HTTP response status of the `post` call in my service from my component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't how one typically does services. Return *the `Observable`* [from the service](https://angular.io/guide/http) and subscribe in the component:

#### Component

```js
public saveComment() {
    this._service.postComment(this.comment)
        .subscribe(
            success => this.getComments(),  // See new method below, just ignore `success`.
            error => handleError(error)
        );
}

public getComments() {
    this._service.getComments()
        .subscribe(
             comments => this.comments = comments,
             error => this.handleError(error),
             () => doSomethingElseOnceComplete(),
        );
}
```

#### Service

```js
public postComment(comment: string) {
    return this._http.post(this.serviceUrl, { comment });
}

public getComments(comment: string) {
    return this._http.get(this.serviceUrl);
}
```

See my addition on `getComments()`: you probably want to do the same thing and wrap it in a helper function and not make it async. This is the point of using `Observable`s: you pass those around and act on them, very much like a `Promise`.

#### What happens?

The `next` callback (here illustratively assigned to `success`) will be called with the value of whatever the REST returned, which is nothing, but we don't care, so you can just ignore it and the fact that it is `null`.

You can use the fact that the `next` callback will be called *only if the request succeeds* in order to trigger your following dependent action, refreshing comments.

You can handle the error in which the comment failed to post in that error handler.

Also note that as of angular 4.3, [`HttpClientModule`](https://angular.io/guide/http) replaces the older HttpModule, which will eventually be deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. This cleared some things up for me.

Comment: @RyanBuening Glad to hear it! And you're quite welcome. I had a heck of a time ramping up on the Observable model, but I'm sold: it's very powerful once you get the hang of it.